# JSON with \x26 in values breaks PHPs json_decode

Tags: php, javascript, json, browser, google-api

https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query=madonna#

The JSON result is breaking PHPs json_decode. To be exact, the following string is breaking decoding: "Sticky \x26amp; Sweet Tour".

Browsers however seem to be able to understand it: http://jsfiddle.net/nggX2/ & http://jsfiddle.net/QUVFt/

http://jsonlint.com/ claims it's invalid JSON.

On PHP's side I've tried: http://codepad.viper-7.com/suUbQD and http://codepad.viper-7.com/QjqCH7

Any thoughts on what's going on?

Comment: Why are you trying to decode a string thats not in JSON format?

Comment: Why do you say it's not in JSON format?

Comment: jsonlint.com says invalid for me. I don't think `\x` notation is allowed in JSON. Shouldn't it be `\u0026`?

Comment: It is just a string, it can contain whatever characters you want it to contain.  The problem is JSON parser is crashing. It seems this string is coming from/to xml, but that's not the issue.

Comment: What is actually in the database for that value? Is it "Sticky \x26amp; Sweet Tour", "Sticky & Sweet Tour", or "Sticky &amp; Sweet Tour" ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What's going on is that this is invalid JSON. The response from that url is incorrect--JSON doesn't allow the `\xXX` two-digit hexadecimal binary escape sequences, only `\uXXXX` unicode code point escape sequences. Here it should just be `&`, though--no escape sequence needed.

No idea why google/freebase is outputting invalid JSON.

Comment: Why do browsers understand it though?

Comment: It's a valid javascript construct, so either the browsers are being permissive in the JSON they accept (`JSON.parse` example) or are using some kind of `eval()` mechanism to evaluate the JSON (`$.getJSON()` with JSONP example). You should not depend on this behavior.

Comment: `No idea why google/freebase is outputting invalid JSON.` - indeed, this seems like a bug that needs to be reported - or if it is by design, explained. And +1.

Comment: @Peeter because the examples are using JSONP (which technically has nothing to do with JSON). JSONP is evaluated as javascript, which is a different language. Valid JSON is not necessarily valid javascript and vice versa.

Comment: Oh didn't look at the other test, it was invalid. It should be http://jsfiddle.net/QUVFt/1/ (Correctly reports as invalid JSON). Common mistake with 2-level interpretation. The JSON parser saw `&amp;` after javascript parser. So there needs to be `"\\x26"` to pass `\x26` to the JSON parser.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON should look like the following:

```
"Sticky \\x26amp; SweetTour"
```

The slash needs to be escaped, because it is the escape char.

Comment: @Peeter because you're only escaping the string once, so a double slash gets eaten by your single quotes. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/arq5J/1/