# Can't figure out a way to escape quotes in json in YouTube API

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, youtube, youtube-api

I am using the YouTube API and I'm using Python urllib2.urlopen() to send a GET request. Then I pass the result to Javascript. (I'm using Django)

So, something like this:

```
result = urllib2.urlopen('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?'+query+'&max-results=1&alt=json')
```

I'm using jQuery to parse the JSON formatted response, however some YouTube videos/descriptions have double quotes and this breaks the parseJSON() function.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Example data? Tracebacks perhaps?

Comment: for example... {"test": ""quoted material""} ...this wouldn't work, and that's the kind of result some of the Youtube videos return. There's quotes inside that aren't escaped, and this breaks the parser.

Comment: does this mean i'm screwed and i need to hack away at some crazy code to try to catch those random quotes?

Comment: Can you give an example query that returns such results? I have otherwise hard time believing that youtube would return invalid json..

Comment: @Esailija It's not that hard to imagine, unfortunately :( Historically, at least, Google [*gasp!*] and Facebook have returned invalid JSON from different services/queries. (But it is always nice to have *current live proof* of an invalid service.)

Comment: @Esailija http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021041/detecting-and-parsing-escape-character-from-a-json-file (for instance)

Comment: Well yeah, but here's plenty of quotes and it's working fine http://jsfiddle.net/bZfqe/ I also verified that the json is valid in the unpadded version as well.

Comment: @Esailija JSONLint also validates *that link* (I wish one could "share" a JSONLine paste). However, post says "some", so I wonder what such a "some" link is ..

Comment: @volk If an *exact* link to the JSON in question can be included .. with an *exact* paste of the result .. (Please *update the question*.)

Comment: okay guys, sorry for the waste of time... but the error was on my end (obviously) ..the error started with the fact that I didn't realize Django automatically escapes HTML characters due to security, and I hacked my own way of ignoring special HTML chars like "&quot;" , which ended up malforming the json.

Comment: @pst haha, tbh that does not even try to be JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error was on my end (obviously) ..the error started with the fact that I didn't realize Django automatically escapes HTML characters due to security, and I hacked my own way of ignoring special HTML chars like  & quot; which ended up malforming the json.

the easy fix (in case anybody uses django and ever runs into this problem) to escape special HTML chars is with {{ var|safe }} ..

Comment: Django escapes on input? sounds like [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) syndrome.

Comment: @Esailija: No, on output. Unless told otherwise.

Comment: Ah that's totally different then, sorry. It's the escaping on input that's evil :P